# PHP MYSql: UPDATE Multi Row With One id

Tags: php, mysql

I Fetch this data from Tags Table with `comma separated` :

```
trance, house, electronica, dubstep, club
```

Tags Table Is:

```
ID        NAME             ArticleId
1         trance              10
2         house               10 
3         electronica         10
4         dubstep             10
5         garage              10
```

Now I need To `UPDATE` Tags Table With This New Input For Edit Page:

```
trance, house, electronica  // I remove dubstep, club tag
```

My `PHP` Code:

```
$arr_tag = explode(",",$tag); 
   foreach($arr_tag as $tags){
      DataAccess::put("UPDATE tags SET name = ?, type=? WHERE article = 10",$tags,"news");
   }
```

Now After `UPDATE` Ouput Is:

```
trance, trance, trance
```

My Problem Is: How To `UPDATE` Tags Table For New Tag Input?

Comment: done any basic debugging yousrelf, e.g. `var_dump($tag)`, and `var_dump($arr_tag)` to see what you're working with? As well, note that your update query will simply set ONE tag each time, replacing the tag that was set in the previous update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete all informations first:

```
query = "DELETE FROM tags WHERE article = 10"
```

Then you save all rows again.
Very easy

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your update query is replacing any rows who its article is 10 with whatever tag is the current one in the foreach loop, and the end result is that you're replacing them with the last value of your tags array. I recommend you to first delete all the relevant rows then insert them again with the information you want, but in top of all, I recommend you to read more about PHP and SQL queries in general, as you seems to be lacking in both.